# Implementation of AutoBrightness

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-sensors

I want to add an auto-brightness feature to my android framework.currently the auto-brightness feature is by default disabled in the JB source code. 
The actual scenario is,when i check the checkbox from

> Settings>Display>Brightness>AutoBrightness

the light sensor should returns the current lux value,and depending on the lux value returned, my screen brightness should adjust.
I went trough several docs and Stack-Overflow questions,but got confused on whether i use AsyncTask or a Service to implement such functionality. Any Solution or guidence would appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a service that listens for light sensor changes and changes the screen brightness in response. There is at least one app I've seen that does this, I think, but I am not sure it checks the system AutoBrightness setting.